# Valid void Return Statements from Lambda Expressions (Example: Runnable)

Tags: java, lambda, runnable, unary-operator

Seeing some stranger behavior in Java regarding functional interfaces with `void` return type.

Can someone please explain why the declarations for `task5` and `task6` below compile?

```
public class Test {

    private static int counter;

    private static void testRunnable() {
        /* Runnable has a void return type so the following won't compile.
        * Error message is Void methods cannot return a value. (Java 67108969) Makes sense... */
        // Runnable task1 = () -> { return counter; };
        // Runnable task2 = () -> { return counter + 1; };
        // Runnable task3 = () -> counter;
        // Runnable task4 = () -> counter + 1;

        /* But for some reason, this is totally acceptable. Why? */
        Runnable task5 = () -> counter++;
        Runnable task6 = () -> ++counter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lambda expression `() -> counter++;` is valid as `counter++;` is a statement expression. This is explicitly permitted in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3):

> If the function type's result is void, the lambda body is either a statement expression (§14.8) or a void-compatible block.

And for the [statement expression's definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8):

> An expression statement is executed by evaluating the expression; if the expression has a value, the value is discarded.

If you read the whole JLS 15.27.3, you'll see why `() -> {return counter + 1;}` is not void-compatible. A lambda body is not validated with the exact same rules as the simple expression statement.

In other words, `counter++;` and `++counter;` are statement expressions, meaning that the expression can be evaluated and be treated as a statement whose result is simply discarded.

It's clearer (or rather more familiar-looking) when converted to a block body:

```
Runnable task5 = () -> {
    counter++; //result discarded, but you can't use "return counter++;"
};
Runnable task6 = () -> {
    ++counter; //result discarded, but you can't use "return ++counter;"
};
```

---

This has nothing to do with `UnaryOperator`, at least as far as that functional interface is concerned. It just happens that `counter++` is compatible with `IntUnaryOperator`, but the expression could have been anything else, including (but not limited to) the following, and your question would still apply as the statement yields a result:

```
Runnable task5 = () -> counter += 1;
Runnable task6 = () -> counter = counter + 1;
Runnable task7 = () -> Math.addExact(counter, 1); // no change in counter
Runnable task8 = () -> return2(); //return2 takes no input
```

All these are int-producing expressions that are congruent with `Runnable.run()`. Specifically, `task8` takes no input but produces a result; and it is not even compatible with any unary operator functional interface.

Comment: Just a question "is valid as the statement counter++; is void-compatible " and "In other words, counter++; and ++counter; are statement expressions," So counter++ is a void-compatible or a statement expression ?

Comment: @dreamcrash I'd put it as `counter++;` is a statement expression. Maybe my reference to void-compatible on that element is confusing because the JLS cares more about void-compatible blocks. Statement expressions are just okay to be used for void-returning functions. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

> /* But for some reason, this is totally acceptable. Why? */
> Runnable task5 = () -> counter++;
> Runnable task6 = () -> ++counter;

Because both tasks *return* void. `counter++;` and `++counter` are operations who's results will be discarded. Moreover, none of them will be interpreted by the compiler as `return counter++;` or `return ++counter;`.

Task 1 and task 2 does not work for obvious reasons, both return and int:

```
 Runnable task1 = () -> { return counter; };
 Runnable task2 = () -> { return counter + 1;};
```

Task 3 and task 4 although do not explicit return and int, both do return implicitly an int:

```
Runnable task3 = () -> counter;
Runnable task4 = () -> counter + 1;
```

Task 1 and tasks are semantically the same as task 3 and task4 it is just syntax sugar.

In the task 1 and task 2, `() -> { return counter; };` and `() -> { return counter + 1;};` are *statement lambda* that can be replaced with the expression lambda `() -> counter;` and `() -> counter + 1;`, respectively

Answer (score 0):

**Example to understand the concept with these two functional interface:**

```
Exp: 1. interface having method with void return type

interface InterfaceNameOne{
    void methodOne();  // method has void return type
}

InterfaceNameOne ref1 = () -> statement1;  // here should not be a return statement

Exp: 2. interface having method with any return type here int as example

interface InterfaceNameTwo{
    int methodTwo(int x);  // method has return type
}

InterfaceNameTwo ref2 = (x) -> {return statement;};  // here should be a return statement
InterfaceNameTwo ref3 = (x) -> statement;  // it is also a return statement
```

While **Runnable is a functional interface** like the first (1) example that's why there must not be a return statement like

```
Runnable ref4 = () -> counter=counter+1; // equivalent to counter++ & ++counter without return statement

But not like

Runnable ref5 = () -> counter; // equivalent to return statement
Runnable ref6 = () -> {return counter;}; // equivalent to return statement
```